# SQL, CREAR UNA FUNCION QUE REEMPLAZE UN DATO

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo que hacer una función la cual
la idea es que dado un idioma
busque el texto de ese idioma
y si no lo encuentra
retornas el valor recibido

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_traduce_memo]
( @idioma char (4), @codigo char(4),@textotraducir varchar(500) 
returns VARCHAR(800)

     BEGIN
     IF @idioma = 'ESPA' 
   select Codtraducir  from Traduccion where Codtraducir = 'ESPA'-- esto nose como se debe mostrar la oracion va a mostrar toda la tabla

   return Memotraducir = Traduccion

   END
   
   ELSE
   BEGIN
   return  @idioma=@idioma, @codigo=@codigo @textotraducir=@textotraducir

   END
```

Esta db nombrada , traduccion , tira la siguiente respuesta

```
--IDTRADUCCION  CODTRADUCCION     CODTRADUCIR        MEMOTRADUCIR                  TRADUCCION
--296            ACAT              ESPA           Accommodation at              Alojamiento en
--297             INA              ESPA              in a                         en
--298             FOR              ESPA             for                           Por
--299            NIGH              ESPA           night/s                       noche/s
```

Tengo que hacer que lo que este en memotraducir tome la tabla de Traducción
desde  ya gracias.[image: Imagen]
La consulta esta comentada ya que esto no es el servidor real si no un entorno propio

Comment: Esta es una idea terrible. La gramática en cada idioma es distinta y utilizar un traductor palabra por palabra generará errores incomprensibles o que pueden ser ofensivas.

Comment: Lo sé, perola traducción  es puntual para una sola lineá a raíz de un pequeño error ,  por eso me pidieron esto, a mi también me parece una terrible idea, pero lamentablemente soy el que tiene que realizar

Comment: Independientemente de que sea buena o mala idea, deberías de poner una pregunta bien definida. Un ejemplo de una tabla, con unas filas. Y además del código que has intentado, un ejemplo de la salida esperada. [example]. La valoración de si es recomendable, o no, se basa en opiniones.

Comment: Yo en la pregunta veo, **Crear una función que reemplace un dato**, y personalmente me parece una muy buena pregunta, dado que no tengo los datos, y no se para cuantas filas, ni textos tienes que emplearla.